# установка SetMaxWorkerThreads в TThreadPool

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Я разбираюсь с методами параллельного программирования в delphi xe7.

Конкретно меня интересует параллельный цикл `TParallel.For`.

У него в свойствах есть параметр `Pool` типа `TThreadPool`. При попытке манипулировать этим параметром у меня возникла пара вопросов.

У него есть свойство `SetMaxWorkerThreads`, которое задает максимального количество потоков в пуле (как я понял оно оттлакивается от количества ядер в системе), но я хочу установить свое значение, но какое бы значение я не ставил у меня все равно создается только 10 потоков в пуле. Почему? И как мне сделать так, чтобы у меня выполнялось больше 10 потоков одновременно?

Пример кода:

```
Pool := TThreadPool.Create;
Pool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(150);
TParallel.For(0, 3000, procedure(i: Integer)
  begin
    Sleep(100);
  end, Pool);
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `SetMinWorkerThreads`

Comment: Пробовал. Эффект аналогичный.